# how to get return value from the the subroutine functrion to the main function?

Tags: c++

I would like to ask very simple question that sometime make me confuse.

I want to get a value from the subroutine function, but I tried many ways still don't get it out,

Here is my code:

```
void Read_line (string filename)
{
    int number_of_lines = 0;
    std::string line1;
    std::ifstream myfile(filename.c_str());

    while (std::getline(myfile, line1))
    {
        ++number_of_lines;
    }
    cout << "Number of lines in text file: " << number_of_lines;

//  return number_of_lines;
}

int main ()
{

    string name = "gbm";
    double WEEK = 1930;
    double DAY = 0;

    string week = boost::lexical_cast<string>(WEEK);  // convert number to string
    string day  = boost::lexical_cast<string>(DAY) ;  // convert number to string

    string filename = name + week + day + ".sp3";
    int number_of_lines = Read_line(filename);

   // my expectation to have "number_of_lines" value in here

   cout << "Number of lines in text file: " << number_of_lines;

}
```

Thank you for helps.

Comment: Any C tutorial should explain how to get the result of a function. The function needs to use a `return` statement, and you need to change the function declaration to say what type it returns.

Comment: you can not return a different type other than the function's declaraion's

Comment: @ChristianHackl, obviously because the code was copied, and than another assingment was given by the teacher upon suspicion of the code authorship.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the function to return `int` instead of `void`. Then you'll be able to uncomment the `return` statement.

```
int Read_line (string filename)
{
    ...
    return number_of_lines;
}
```